# What's the probability a random number is at least twice as big as another?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Two numbers $m,n$ are chosen from a normal distribution, i.e. the chance that either number lies between $a$ and $b$ is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_a^be^{-x^2}dx$$
Edit: you could also say $e^{-x^2}/\sqrt{2\pi}$ is the probability density function.

What's the probability that $n\ge 2m$?

Comment: What do you mean? If you're using a normal distribution on $[a,b]$ you need to renormalize the measure. And the answer depends on which integer you're choosing from the interval.

Comment: Also, this question has an inherent flaw:  how do you define the probability for integers? You can do it via intervals, like $\Bbb P(n<x\le n+1)$ but then what priviledges that inverval over $n-1/2<x\le n+1/2$ or something else with different measure?

Comment: Note that the joint distribution function is radially symmetric, and the line $x=2y$ cuts it in half.  So the answer can only be $p=1/2$.

Comment: Note that you either need to replace $-x^2$ by $-{x^2 \over 2}$ or adjust the constant in the formulae above.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ be iid random variables from $N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ 
So you want to find 
$$P(X_{1}\geq 2X_{2})=P(X_{1}-2X_{2}\geq0)$$
where $-2X_{2}\sim N(-2\mu,4\sigma^{2})$ thus $X_{1}-2X_{2}\sim N(-\mu,5\sigma^{2})$ so converting to a standard normal with $Z=\dfrac{(X_{1}-2X_{2})+\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{5}}\sim N(0,1)$ we have 
$$=P\left(Z\geq \frac{\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{5}}\right)$$
And you can find that with standard normal table

Also note the reason why I use $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ is because when you say "two numbers are chosen from a normal distribution" this just means your sampling from distribution where $X_{1}$ represents first sample and $X_{2}$ represents second sample.

Comment: I am not familiar with a standard normal table, could you elaborate on that point?

Comment: http://www.pavementinteractive.org/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/Normal_table.gif

Comment: Don't need to use the standard normal table per se. You can use computer software. For example, in Microsoft Excel you could type "=1 - norm.s.dist(mu/(sigma*sqrt(5),TRUE)", assuming you knew what sigma and mu were.

Comment: where the z will be $\frac{\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{5}}$ and probability given from table will be for $\leq$ so you will have to subtract that by 1

Comment: Also you can do what DavidButlerUofA suggested

Comment: Als note in the example you gave you had $N(0,1)$ case so your z=0 thus p=0.5

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something, the answer is ${1 \over 2}$.

Note that the pdf. for each variable should either be ${1 \over \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{- { x^2 \over 2}}$ or ${1 \over \sqrt{\pi}} e^{- { x^2 }}$ in order to
normalize to one when integrated. I will use the latter, but the answer is the same regardless (irregardless :-).

You want to compute $p= {1 \over \pi} \int_A  e^{-\|x\|^2} dx$,
where $A=\{x | x_2 \ge 2x_1 \}$. Note that $A$ is a half-space, so we can find a rotation so that $Q A = \{ x | x_2 \ge 0 \}$. The change of variables theorem
gives
$\int_A  e^{-\|x\|^2} dx = \int_{QA}  e^{-\|Q^{-1}x\|^2} dx = \int_{\{ x | x_2 \ge 0 \}}  e^{-\|x\|^2} dx $, from which we get $p= {1 \over 2}$.

Answer (score 0):

As mjqxxxx says, the joint distribution is circularly symmetric.  So, if you are looking for the probability that $|n|>2|m|$, then it equals the part of the circle for which $|\tan\theta|>2$  This is $4(\pi/2-\arctan2$, so the probability would be $1-(2/\pi)\arctan 2$.

Comment: This is a creative approach. However, doesn't this assume that $m$ and $n$ are chosen from between $0$ and $1$ uniformly randomly, instead of over all of $\mathbb{R}$ according to a normal distribution? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I have said $|n|>2|m|$ rather than $n>2m$, so I took absolute values to make them positive.  I have included $n=-2.1,m=0.3$ for example.  By the way, if $m$ and $n$ were uniformly between 0 and 1, the probability would be 1/4.